# NSNotificationCenter one post causes observers to be called twice

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following code:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNewsfeedFetchCompleted object:self userInfo:userinfo];
```

only this, no where else. And here's how I set the observer:

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(newsfeedFetchCompleted:) name:kNewsfeedFetchCompleted object:nil];
```

question is when I do one post the newsfeedFetchCompleted is called twice.. how is this even possible?

Comment: [[NSNotification defaultCenter]removeObserver:self]

Comment: what do you mean? why should I even do that?

Comment: AddObserver could be getting called more than once for the same object, resulting in multiple notifications.  Where are you calling addObserver?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is possible when your code for addObserver is executed twice. The notification function will be called as many times as it is registered.

So make sure your code for adding observer is executed for once only. So, you can keep it in viewDidLoad or init method.

If you are putting it in viewWillAppear then remove observer in viewWillDisAppear.

Comment: I actually added this in initWithNib name

Comment: In that case, when you are deallocating that viewcontroller, you have missed to removeObserver in dealloc method.

Comment: So, if the view controller is created second time, your observer will get registered again and the function will called twice.

Comment: Check whether your dealloc method is getting called or not?
One more thing you can do is, before adding observer, remove the observer.

Answer (score 7):

before you add observer, make sure you remove the previous observer added.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(newsfeedFetchCompleted:) name:kNewsfeedFetchCompleted object:nil];
```

Comment: This should have more up votes. Really helped me fix an issue where my method was getting called too many times.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible if you have added the same observer multiple times for the `newsfeedFetchCompleted` notification.  You should match your addObserver calls with removeObserver calls.

For example if you added the observer in viewWillAppear/viewWillDidAppear/ViewDidLoad of a UIViewController, you should remove it in viewWillDisappear/viewDidDisappear/ViewDidUnload.

The corresponding remove call for addObserver, is `removeObserver:name:object:`

More info can be found in the [NSNotificationCenter docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)